# How do I set CommandTimeout to Never Timeout in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I see a lot of questions about setting a timeout value but none asking about an infinite timeout. We have a stored proc that can take over an hour to stage data for a process. So I was thinking it would be better to just set the CommandTimeout to never timeout. I know there are issues with this approach.

[ObjectContext.CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

I was reading the MS documentation for CommandTimeout and it doesn't really say anything regarding never timing out so I'm thinking one approach is to just set an arbitrarily high number. Or maybe go with double the average processing time.

Answer (score 2):

So according to [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) you can accomplish this by setting it to 0. On the documentation you linked, it says it throws `ArgumentException` if the timeout is less than 0. Have you tried using 0 as the timeout?

Comment: You may be correct, the documentation does state `0` is allowed to be used, but it doesn't say it will become infinite.

Comment: No it doesn't say it. But if it's allowed and it works that way in other classes, it's worth a try right? :)

Comment: Yeah, well `ObjectContext` doesn't mention `0`, only pitfall is that it also is near the `ArgumentException`.

Comment: True. His other option is to set it to something over `3600` to account for his hour-long procedure.